# docker images alpine3.14 compile nginx 1.21.1 error，however docker images alpine3.12 is ok，why?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I try to compile docker images from `alpine:3.14`.
The error is as follows

```sh
make -f objs/Makefile
make: make: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:10: build] Error 127
```

Then I switched to version `alpine:3.12`, `alpine:3.13 and` found that both are OK!

The following is my key problematic code for compiling NGINX based on `alpine:3.14` version

```sh
# Omit irrelevant code

RUN  \
                addgroup  -S www  &&  adduser www  -D -S -s /bin/sh -G www  \
                && wget -P /home/soft  https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts/archive/v0.1.18.tar.gz  \
                && wget -P /home/soft  http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.21.1.tar.gz   \
                && wget -P /home/soft  https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.44.tar.gz    \
                &&  cd /home/soft  && tar -zxf nginx-1.21.1.tar.gz  &&  tar  -zxf  v0.1.18.tar.gz   && tar  -zxf  pcre-8.44.tar.gz  \
                &&  cd /home/soft/nginx-1.21.1  \
                &&  ./configure --user=www --group=www --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module  --with-http_v2_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-stream --with-http_sub_module  --with-pcre=/home/soft/pcre-8.44   --add-module=/home/soft/nginx-module-vts-0.1.18  \
                &&  make && make install  \

# Omit irrelevant code
```

Comment: Could you include enough of the irrelevant code that we can reproduce your error?

Comment: Seeing a relevant excerpt of the Makefile would also be really helpful.  (Can you use the Docker Hub `nginx` image instead of building your own?)

Answer (score 0):

Error 127 seven could mean two things. Either the the binary for the command is not found in PATH variable (Please take a note here, sometimes it can also happen that the command is found but some library is missing) or the binary doesn't have the execution permissions. By the look of it, I suspect it's because it doesn't have the execution permissions.

I would suggest you to run the alpine:3.14 container and inspect the PATH variable, the make binary location and the permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find that other people have also encountered this problem  https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/182